# Error: Scope parameter is not authorized: r_contactinfo

Tags: linkedin-api

I get the following error by using the LinkedIn API: **Error: Scope parameter is not authorized: r_contactinfo**

```
throw new Error("Scope parameter is not authorized: " + p);
```

The application was working for month, and actually I don't want to deploy again because of this issue. Is there any way to fix this, I guess it's connected to the LinkedIn API?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://platform.linkedin.com/in.js">
    api_key: 75x5459m1lbbde
    onLoad: OnLinkedInFrameworkLoad
    authorize: true
    scope: r_basicprofile rw_groups r_contactinfo
</script>
```

best

M

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`r_contactinfo` is no longer openly available, as per LinkedIn's API change announcement from back in February (https://developer.linkedin.com/blog/posts/2015/developer-program-changes).

You would need to apply for and be approved to be in one of their partnership programs to continue using it, or you will have to stop requesting that member permission to continue functioning.